# adding Jquery to Sharepoint 2010

Tags: jquery

I would like to add Jquery Accordion code for Sharepoint 2010.  I have added jquery-1.9.1.js & jquery-ui.js file in _layouts\JScript folder. Now I want to add below code sharepoint designer. Please help where I can add this.

```
<div id="accordion">
<h3>Heading 1</h3>
<div class="accordion-content">
    <p>jQuery UI 1.10 includes dozens of bug fixes and improved accessibility. In addition, the dialog and progressbar widgets have undergone '</p>
```

Comment: Is this in a master page, page layout or something else?  Where are you including the actually jQuery includes?  What kind of problem are you seeing that is preventing you from doing this?

Comment: I have added JQuery files in .....\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\Jscript folder(custom folder). Then I added scriptlink _layouts/CustomJScripts/jquery-1.9.1.js. in Sharepoint designer for default loading. Then i added above Accordion code in Sharepoint designer but it didn't work.

Comment: <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
<script>
This code also I added in sharepoint designer.

Comment: Did you check in? Publish?

Answer (score 1):

Use a CustomAction element with the target of ScriptLink, or a DelegateControl targeting AdditionalPageHead.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to put your accordian script into a [$(document).ready();](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) block as it sounds like it is executing either before the jQuery scripts are loaded or before the html itself has been fully loaded into the DOM.